# SignalR custom ScaleoutMessageBus memory leak

Tags: memory-leaks, signalr

I implement simple ScaleoutMessageBus. I override Send method and send message to all configured nodes. And It works, but when system is under heavy load memory of w3wp process grows. When I create dump I saw that almost all memory is held in SignalR Message objects. Does any body know what I doing wrong?

Thanks

Martin

Update added ScaleOutBus class

```
public class ScaleoutMessageBus : Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Messaging.ScaleoutMessageBus
      {
        private static long sNextId = long.MinValue;
        private readonly List<string> proxiesEndpointName;
        private static readonly object Lock = new object();

        /// <summary>
        ///   Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ScaleoutMessageBus" /> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="resolver">The resolver.</param>
        /// <param name="config">The configuration.</param>
        public ScaleoutMessageBus(IDependencyResolver resolver, ScaleoutConfiguration config)
          : base(resolver, config)
        {
          proxiesEndpointName = new List<string>(config.NodeEndpoints);
          Open(0);
        }

        private void Received(int streamIndex, long id, byte[] data)
        {
          ScaleoutMessage message = ScaleoutMessage.FromBytes(data);
          var uid = unchecked((ulong)id);
          lock (Lock)
          {
            OnReceived(streamIndex, uid, message);
          }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sends the specified stream index.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="streamIndex">Index of the stream.</param>
        /// <param name="messages">The messages.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        protected override Task Send(int streamIndex, IList<Message> messages)
        {
          var messageToSend = new ScaleoutMessage(messages);
          var bytesToSend = messageToSend.ToBytes();
          return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
          {
            Parallel.ForEach(proxiesEndpointName.Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)), s =>
            {
              try
              {
                var proxy = new ChannelProxyWrapper<IBackplaneService>(s).GetTransparentProxy();
                proxy.Send(streamIndex, bytesToSend);
              }
              catch (Exception ex)
              {
                LogHelper.WriteException(ex, TraceEventType.Warning, "Cannot send message to node {0}", s);
              }
            });
          });
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Sends the specified stream index.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="streamIndex">Index of the stream.</param>
        /// <param name="data">The data.</param>
        public void Send(int streamIndex, byte[] data)
        {
          long id = Interlocked.Increment(ref sNextId);
          Received(streamIndex, id, data);
        }
      }
```

Comment: You should show your code, otherwise it's difficult to help.